# Full Screen Content Slider Only Slides Right

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, css-transitions

I am currently working on a full-screen slider that should go to the left or right depending on which button the user clicks. It works wonderfully when clicking next, but when clicking previous the slider just fades in, instead of sliding despite having the same code (but opposite margin) to the next button.

Here is what I'm doing (next and prev buttons):

```
    $("#prevproject").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //subtract 1 from i unless i is 0, then set i = 12 (last element)

    if (i == 0) {
      i = 12;
    } else {
      i = i - 1;
    }
    $('#project').attr('data-name', projects[i]);
    $('#project #slide').animate({
          'marginRight': '25%',
          'opacity': 0
        }, 200, function() {

          switchProjects(projects[i]);

          $('#project #slide').css({
            'marginRight': '-25%'
          });
          $('#project #slide').animate({
            'marginRight': '0',
            'opacity': 1
          }, 200);
          //=================================
});




});

$("#nextproject").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //add 1 from i unless i is 12, then set i = 0

    if (i == 12) {
      i = 0;
    } else {
      i = i + 1;
    }

    $('#project').attr('data-name', projects[i]);
    $('#project #slide').animate({
          'marginLeft': '25%',
          'opacity': 0
        }, 200, function() {

          switchProjects(projects[i]);

          $('#project #slide').css({
            'marginLeft': '-25%'
          });
          $('#project #slide').animate({
            'marginLeft': '0',
            'opacity': 1
          }, 200);
          //=================================
});
```

I have a container div with an inner div, and put the slide effect on the inner div. Content is loaded via the switchProjects function when off screen and slides back in with the new content.

```
 <div id="project">
  <div id="slide">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column small-12 medium-4">
      <h4></h4>
      <p></p>
      <img alt="" id="map"/> </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Works pretty well for the next but not previous. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking. The resolution was to set the marginLeft to the inverse of what I was doing in the next function vs setting marginRight.

```
$('#project #slide').animate({
          'marginLeft': '-25%',
          'opacity': 0
        }, 200, function() {

          switchProjects(projects[i]);

          $('#project #slide').css({
            'marginLeft': '25%'
          });
          $('#project #slide').animate({
            'marginLeft': '0',
            'opacity': 1
          }, 200);
          //=================================
});
```